# Linker error in USB HID Code for Microchip PIC (MPLAB/C18)

Tags: usb, hid, microchip, mplab, mplab-c18

I'm trying to compile some code for basic USB HID functionality. I'm using a PIC18F14K50 with MPLAB 8.43 and the Microchip C18 compiler.

I'm using some standard files from Microchip's website. [Here is my C file](http://pastebin.com/YmVV1jrB) and [here is my header file](http://pastebin.com/bxzS33Xr).

I'm getting the following error when I build:

> Executing: "C:\Program Files\Microchip\mplabc18\v3.40\bin\mplink.exe" /p18F14K50 /l"C:\MCC18\lib" /k"C:\MCC18\bin\LKR" "usb_function_hid.o" "usb_device.o" "enumeration.o" "usb_descriptors.o" /u_CRUNTIME /u_DEBUG /z__MPLAB_BUILD=1 /z__MPLAB_DEBUG=1 /o"C:\LPCUSBDK_Labs\Lab1_files\output\Project Lab 1.cof" /M"C:\LPCUSBDK_Labs\Lab1_files\output\Project Lab 1.map" /W
>
> MPLINK 4.40, Linker
>
> Device Database Version 1.3
>
> Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Microchip Technology Inc.
>
> Error - could not find definition of symbol 'HIDDescriptor1' in file './usb_function_hid.o'.
>
> Errors    : 1
>
> Link step failed.

The `HIDDescriptor1` symbol appears in 2 places in the code: PasteBin line 173 of the C file and PasteBin line 356 of the header file.

This code comes straight from Microchip. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be linking. I think either it's designed for another version of the compiler, I'm missing some external dependency, or I'm missing some compiler/linker switches.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header file, you have `HIDDescriptor1` defined externally.  So when you compile usb_function_hid.c, it will compile fine until you try to link it.  Then, it cant find that symbol.

It seems that you have to define `HIDDescriptor1` in your own code.  Or else it is somewhere else in the source that you downloaded, and you need to link that in as well.  But it surely isn't defined in the .c file.

EDIT:

I downloaded and installed the [Microchip Application Libraries](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784).  There is no longer any mention of HIDDescriptor1 in any of the source.  However, `usb_function_hid.h` details another structure that I assume is a replacement:

```
//USB HID Descriptor header as detailed in section 
//"6.2.1 HID Descriptor" of the HID class definition specification
typedef struct _USB_HID_DSC
{
    BYTE bLength;           //offset 0 
    BYTE bDescriptorType;           //offset 1
    WORD bcdHID;            //offset 2
    BYTE bCountryCode;      //offset 4
    BYTE bNumDsc;           //offset 5


    //USB_HID_DSC_HEADER hid_dsc_header[HID_NUM_OF_DSC];
    /* HID_NUM_OF_DSC is defined in usbcfg.h */

} USB_HID_DSC;
```

Browsing the example projects, there are many many HID projects, all which build just fine with the C18 compiler.  I recommend downloading this library again; you may have an incomplete or older library.  The highlighted project below is for the PIC18F14K50.

[image: Microchip Application Libraries\USB\Device - HID - Keyboard\Firmware]

Comment: This much is obvious. But like I said, the code comes direct from Microchip and they provide nothing in their instructions relating to having to define `HIDDescriptor`. Furthermore, if I needed to define it myself, then it wouldn't have been labelled `extern`.

Comment: Sorry for pointing out the obvious; one never knows on this site where people's experience is.  My thinking is that your device should provide its own `HIDDescriptor`, filled in with all the fields to make it correct, and name it `HIDDescriptor1`.  Let me look into the code a little; is the source that which comes with C18 or is there a separate download you used?

Comment: It's a separate download from Microchip as part of their example on how to implement USB HID. I will see if I can dig up the link.

Comment: I downloaded the Microchip Application Libraries and edited my answer above... hope this helps

Comment: Using this library, I was able to make the HID work. Thanks! (I'm not sure what was up with the other Microchip library. Maybe it was obsolete?)